# Show the whole setTitle in AlertDialog.Builder

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to display the whole sentence of the `setTile` in `AlertDialog.Builder` but I am just getting a part display. How can I manage that with `AlertDialog.Builder`?

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

builder.setTitle("Please help us to track the route, has this route arrived the stop? ");
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Your best best is to scratch the Title and and a TextView as its replacement .

Answer (score 1):

For long text (or the only text you're showing) use `setMessage`:

```
builder.setMessage("Please help us to track the route, has this route arrived the stop? ");
```

Use `setTitle` for something short and snappy in addition to a message or use no title at all.

More reading about dialogs:
http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-content

Comment: @Eugine: I am using `OnMultiChoiceClickListener` when I use `setMessage` the checkboxes disappear.

Comment: @MrAsker I'm not an expert on dialogs really. The purpose of the dialog if using a list (single choice or multi choice) should be clear from just the dialog title. Like "Favorite songs" and a list of songs or "Tag friends" and a list of associates. If you can't keep it simple consider changing the flow.

Answer (score 0):

As what @Eugene H suggests, you can remove the title of AlertDialog and use a custom layout XML with a TextView that will serve as your Title.

To do that you need to remove the Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE from the Dialog.

```
final View dialogView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
alertDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

TextView tvTitle = (TextView)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
tvTitle.setText("Please help us to track the route, has this route arrived the stop?");
```

custom_dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_textfield">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is the title"
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"/>

    </LinearLayout>


   <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="This is the Message"
      android:id="@+id/tvMessage"/>   

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/date_time_set"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="OK"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: 1) Forgot to call `setView()`. 2) The layout was inflated with activity context not dialog themed context. Careful with that. Easy fix: `AlertDialog.Builder.getContext()`